# camel FILE component, docu confusion: is option readlock=changed available?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using Camel 2.15 and reading the docu of the [FILE component](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/file2.html). For the "changed" value of the "readLock" option, it states

> This option is **only** avail for the FTP component from Camel 2.8 onwards.

I would understand this statement as: "This option is **not** available for the FILE component. Likewise, it is **not** avalialbe for the FTP component prior to Camel 2.8"

But apparently, the option is doing something for the FILE component. Is the statement in the docu misleading? Or else am I not getting something?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-2934

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its available for the file component. The FTP component extends the file component but the changed readlock was not available for FTP until Camel 2.8 onwards.

So you have changed readlock in the file component, also before Camel 2.8.